# Cloudfront rewrite url to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront domain that servers images from S3 in the form:

http://static.example.com/images/image1.jpg -> S3://mybucket/images/image1.jpg

I need to do a rewrite, so this url works as well:

http://static.example.com/this-is-example/images/image1.jpg -> S3://mybucket/images/image1.jpg

It's possible to do this with cloudfront or another amazon service ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are serving out of S3, the best/easiest thing to do is to use **[S3 Routing Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html)**. Here's an example that should capture what you asked for:

```
  <RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>this-is-example/images/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>images/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
  </RoutingRules>
```

This may need tuning depending on your usage, but it should be fairly easy to add redirect/routing/rewrite rules for this.

[Note you can also add *individual* redirects with a different mechanism](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html).

Comment: Thanks but I as I see I can't add a wildcard for the 'this-is-example' part. Also the routing rule always give a extra 301 permanent redirect. Is there a way to put a wildcard? As I see in documentation, i think is not possible with S3 routing rules...

Comment: it will certainly create a redirect. Wildcards aren't mentioned at all in your question, and there's no way to do a redirect- either an exact match or a prefix. S3 is for static content and URLs, it's not a fully-configurable web server. [There's a strong argument to be made for S3 not being proper webserver at all](http://jdorfman.posthaven.com/medium-bitcoin-660x493-dot-jpg-cdn-vs-s3), in fact.

Comment: This approach seems to work for s3 but I don't believe it works when the content is being served by cloudfront.